# Install npm package on heroku

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I've got my custom discord bot. I downloaded this Extra Life API for Node.js. Locally on my PC works perfect because it can read the node_modules folder where the API is.

I created a extralife.js file inside my commands folder. I'm using modules.

My bot is running on the cloud (heroku) taking the code from github but it can't work with this API.

I want to know how I can install this Extra Life API on heroku to use my commands, same as I do on my PC.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

CODE:

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json'); // config.json is one folfer up ..
const extralifeapi = require('extra-life-api');

module.exports = {
    //name:, cooldown:, args: and description: are properties of the object. They are important to use on the main file.

    name: 'extralife',
    cooldown: 5,
    description: 'extralife!',
    //whenever you set args to true in one of your command files, it'll perform this check and supply feedback if necessary.
    args: true,
    usage: '+ <ARGUMENT>',
    arguments: '<info>, <team + teamID>, <teamdonors + teamID>, <donors + participantID>, <participant + participantID>',
    execute(msg, args) {
        if (args[0] === 'info') {
            extralifeapi.getUserInfo('349069').then(userinfo => {
                return msg.channel.send(`Participant name: ${userinfo.displayName}\nExtra Life team is: ${userinfo.teamName}\nFunraising Goal: ${userinfo.fundraisingGoal}`);
            });
        } else if (args[0] === 'team') {
            let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const extralifTeamid = args1[2]
            extralifeapi.getTeamInfo(`${extralifTeamid}`).then(teaminfo => {
                return msg.channel.send(`Team name: ${teaminfo.name}\nTeam Captain: ${teaminfo.captainDisplayName}\nFunraising Goal: ${teaminfo.fundraisingGoal}\nFunraising Page: ${teaminfo.links.page}\n`);
            });
        } else if (args[0] === 'schedule') {
            return msg.reply('Extra Life stream team schedule: https://community.extra-life.org/forums/topic/4508-the-official-extra-life-stream-team-weekly-schedule/');
        }else if (args[0] === 'donors') {
            let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const extralifeid = args1[2]
            extralifeapi.getUserDonations(`${extralifeid}`).then(Donations => {
                return msg.channel.send(`Total participant donations raised: ${Donations.countDonations}\n`);
            });
        } else if (args[0] === 'teamdonors') {
            let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const extralifeid = args1[2]
            extralifeapi.getTeamDonations(`${extralifeid}`).then(Donations => {
                return msg.channel.send(`Total team donations raised: ${Donations.countDonations}\nTeam ID: ${Donations.donations[0].teamID}\n`);
            });
        } else if (args[0] === 'participant') {
            let args1 = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const extralifeid = args1[2]
            extralifeapi.getUserInfo(`${extralifeid}`).then(userinfo => {
                return msg.channel.send(`Participant name: ${userinfo.displayName}\nExtra Life team is: ${userinfo.teamName}\nExtra Life Team ID: ${userinfo.teamID}\nFunraising Goal: ${userinfo.fundraisingGoal}\nFunraising Page: ${userinfo.links.donate}\nStream Page: ${userinfo.links.stream} `); 
            });
            if (!args[0] === '') {
                return msg.reply('Human you need an Extra Life id in order to use this command');
            }
            //return msg.channel.send(`Do you want to play some rounds? ${taggedUser.username}`);
        }
        //msg.channel.send(`This argument is incorrect for this command, try again human: ${args[0]}`);
    },
};
```

Comment: Heroku should automatically run an `npm install` as you do on your machine (getting all the libraries in the package.json), so that's weird. Check `heroku logs`, do you see any error?

Comment: Hi. How Should I declare this library on package.json because I didn't and works fine. I downloaded on my pc with the specific command: npm i extra-life-api

Comment: `npm i extra-life-api` should be sufficient, as it automatically writes the dependency in the package.json. Can you post the content of your package.json and the code which uses the library?

Comment: I got 2 one on my main \DiscordBot\ folder and it doesn't say nothing about this and another one on node_modules\extra-life-api with a lot of info, this is inside the API folder after the API installation via NPM. It's too long to post here.

Comment: @Michele I fixed adding the dependency on my package.json. Heroku automatically deployed the API. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Glad that you solved it :)